# Qt how to use paintEvent function to refresh two or more widgets silmultaneously

Tags: c++, qt, refresh, paintevent

Now I am using **Qt5** to draw Kline of stocks. Two classes are defined for price bar and volume bar, then I add them to a widget by a **QSplitter**. However, When I move mouse forward or backward and the price-bar chart updates, the volume-bar section will not repaint simultaneously until I put mouse under volume widget. I tried some ideas, but it didn't work. Many thanks.

A part of codes like this:

```
    pvolume = new VolumeBar(this);
    pvolume->setObjectName(tr("volume_bar"));
    pvolume->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);

    pkline = new PriceBar(this);
    pkline->setObjectName("price_bar");
    pkline->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);


    QSplitter *splitterMain = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical, 0); 

    splitterMain->insertWidget(0, pkline);
    splitterMain->insertWidget(1, pvolume);
    splitterMain->setStretchFactor(0, 4);
    splitterMain->setStretchFactor(1, 1);
```

For pricebar, the paintEvent function is overrided as follows,

```
void PriceBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    KLineGrid::paintEvent(event);  // parent of VolumeBar and PriceBar
    drawLine();  // draw price bar
}
```

For VolumeBar, it is overrided like this,

```
void VolumeBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

    KLineGrid::paintEvent(event);
    
    drawYtick();  // y axis
    drawVolume();
}
```

Comment: Hi @sunseeker.yuan, I am trying to understand what exactly you are doing. Some aspects are not yet clear to me: What do yo mean with "move mouse forward or backward" exactly? and why you have "StrongFocus" for a kline?

Comment: IIUC, you want to redraw widget #2 after widget #1 changed it's state. You should emit signal from widget #1 and call `update()` in corresponding slot of widget #2

Comment: @AdrianMaire Thanks for your kindness and sorry for my late.  "move mouse forward or backward" means that when I move the crossline on the kline section to look forward or backward, the volume bar not repaint following, it will update until I click the volume widget gemetry. Otherwise, the stock data has been set into a global data structure.

Comment: @Genjutsu Yes, that's the point. Is there an example for this? I get your meaning, but I don't know how to organize it. Thanks.